# create a scipy.sparse.csr_matrix from a delimited string

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am processing a large amount of binary data, which is coming into my program row by row as strings that look like `\t\t1\t\t1\t\t\t` (but much longer). As you can imagine, these are rows from a tab delimited file.

Obviously, I can do `'\t\t1\t\t1\t\t\t'.split('\t')` and get a list of `1`'s and `''`'s which I can easily enough turn into 1's and 0's or T/F or whatever. However, the data is quite sparse (a lot of 0's and not many 1's) so I am hoping to use some kind of sparse representation.

My question is: does anyone know of a way to go directly from this string to something like a `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix()` *without* having to create an intermediate dense matrix first?

I tried passing the split string (i.e. the list of `1`'s and `''`'s) directly to `csr_matrix()` and I got `TypeError: no supported conversion for types: (dtype('<U1'),)`

As I said, I could do the above and get 1's and 0's and then convert *that* to a `csr_matrix()` but then I'm losing all the speed and memory advantages of the sparse because I'm creating the fully dense version anyway.

Comment: Did you try converting `''`s to `0`s, so `scipy` has a chance to use int types?

Comment: How large is "a large amount"?

Comment: Which style of arguments are you using `directly` with `csr_matrix`?  A dense array?  `(data,(rows, cols))`, `(data, indices, indptr)`?  IN other words elaborate on the `passing ... directly to `csr_matrix`, and why you think that fits with the function's documentation.

Comment: For each line you need to identify which columns have '1'.  From that you can construct the `coo` style of inputs.  In your example, `[2,4]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scipy` cannot interpret your input because it doesn't know you expect the empty string to be converted to a 0. This works fine:

```
>>> from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
>>> x = [0 if not a else int(a) for a in "\t\t\t\t1\t\t\t1\t\t\t".split('\t')] 
>>> csr_matrix(x)
<1x11 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
        with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Make sure your lists are all in a numbrt format prior to matrix-ing.

Following OPs comment I recalled you can force a conversion of empty string to 0, **so a better solution** would be

```
>>> csr_matrix("\t\t\t\t1\t\t\t1\t\t\t".split('\t'),dtype=np.int64)
<1x11 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
        with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

which generates one list less.

Comment: Yes, but that is essentially creating a dense matrix with 1's and 0's (in this example it's just a dense vector, but this is just one row of many). My question is if I can skip this step. In other words, is there a way to tell `csr_matrix()` what value (in my case an empty string) represents `null` or `0` or whatever value is supposed to be "sparsed away"?

Comment: @seth127 do you mean without using split? That iterates your string anyway, and you would need to iterate it once?

Comment: @seth127 I remembered another way to force the data type, but you still have to split the string though. If this still isn't what you mean you will have to clarify.

Comment: No, I was more thinking about memory usage and speed in terms of, with this solution we have three objects: the string, the 1's/0's array, and the sparse matrix. I'm trying to have only the first and third object. Are you saying that just by splitting the string, we have already creating that middle object, so why not just make it a list of 1's and 0's? Bear in mind, the issue is that I'm doing this on a few hundred million of these rows and the strings are ~1k long. That's why I don't want 3 copies of the whole thing.

Comment: @seth127 what array? Yes, splitting a string generates a new list in memory. With my first solution I generated two lists, so the second is better.

Comment: @seth127 but to be clear, as far as I know, you will have the entirety of the data loaded into your program if you wish ti create the `csr_matrix` at once. If memory is an issue you will have to do it in iterations using `vstack`, but that would cost a lot of run time. In any case all of your data has to be retrieved at some point if you want to put it in your matrix.

Comment: That's `sparse.vstack`.  This collects the `coo` attributes of all component matrices, joins them with appropriate offsets, and makes a new `coo` matrix.

Comment: @kabanus that last solution looks promising. I will benchmark them and see if the speed is comparable. Per your comment, yes I think I will have to have the whole thing in memory to create the `car_matrix` which is why I want to make sure I only have _one copy_ of it in memory, which is why I'm concerned about creating these intermediate lists. Am I correct that your final one-liner solution only creates one intermediate object in memory (the split string)? Thank you for all of the help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way of processing the data row by row:

```
In [32]: astr = '\t\t1\t\t1\t\t\t'      # sample row
In [33]: row, col = [],[]
In [34]: for i in range(5):
    ...:     c = [j for j,v in enumerate(astr.split('\t')) if v]
    ...:     row.extend([i]*len(c))
    ...:     col.extend(c)
    ...: data = np.ones(len(col),'int32')
    ...: M = sparse.csr_matrix((data, (row, col)))
    ...: 
In [35]: M
Out[35]: 
<5x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 10 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [36]: M.A
Out[36]: 
array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1]], dtype=int32)
```

For each row I am collecting just the indices of the '1's.  From these I build the corresponding `data` and `row` lists (or arrays). In theory I could construct the `indptr` for a more direct `csr` creation, but the `coo` style is easier to understand.

Intermediate values are:

```
In [40]: c
Out[40]: [2, 4]
In [41]: row
Out[41]: [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]
In [42]: col
Out[42]: [2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4]
In [43]: data
Out[43]: array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int32)
```

Another way to get the `c` values is:

```
In [46]: np.where(astr.split('\t'))[0]
Out[46]: array([2, 4])
```

(but the list comprehension is faster).

string and list `find/index` methods find the first item, but not all.

Comment: This is an interesting option too. Would you even need to split the string? Could you just iterate through the characters of string and increment the column count with every ‘\t’? Maybe that would just be inefficient, but I’m interested in the possibility of never having to split it up OR store the 0’s.